# Number of solutions for homogeneous linear equation represented by matrix $A \in Mat_{3,4}(\mathbb{Z}_{7})$

Tags: linear-algebra, homogeneous-equation

> Let us have a homogeneous linear system of equations which is represented by matrix $A \in Mat_{3,4}(\mathbb{Z}_{7})$. Find the number of solutions depending on parameters $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_{7}$ if
> $$ \begin{pmatrix}
> \overline{2} & \overline{-4} & -b & a+b\\
> \overline{5} & \overline{a} & \overline{1} & \overline{2} \\
> \overline{5}a & \overline{2} & \overline{-3} & a-\overline{3}
> \end{pmatrix} $$.

So what i think I understand is that the even though some of the elements $a$ and $b$ have a horisontal line on them, they are still the members of the field $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$ (the reason why it is a field is that $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$ is a field if $n$ is a prime number).

The rest of the approach to the following task still remains a mystery to me. Because I learn algebra by myself then any helpful tips, tricks and ideas are more than welcome.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You are asked to solve $Ax=0$. Just assume that $K$ is a finite field with $7$ elements. You may think of $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with the usual rules, together with $7=0$. I suppose you know how to solve a system of linear equations, say, over $\Bbb R$? Then just do the same, but with $\Bbb F_7$. And **no**, $\Bbb Z/n$ is not a field for all odd $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that if n is a prime number. Fixed that in the task itself as well... 
Hmm... As i understand then $a$ is exactly the same as $\overline{a}$. That was my main problem that confused me a bit....

Comment: @Goodylan I suspect that the bar over the $a$ was placed there accidentally. Neither $a$ nor $b$ should have a bar.